# Is there a redis package for "Azure cache for Redis" in dart 2.9.2 (for flutter app) which takes hostname, port and its key in the connection string?

Tags: azure, flutter, dart, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to connect my Azure Cache for Redis in a flutter app. Currently I've tried two packages in dart for redis which are [redis 1.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/redis) and [dartis 0.5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/dartis).

Example:

```
import 'package:redis/redis.dart';
...
RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
    conn
        .connect('localhost', 6379)
        .then((Command command) {
      print("yo2");
      command.send_object(["SET", "key1", "value1"]).then((var response) {
        print(response);
      });
    });
```

Instead of "localhost" I put "SampleName.redis.cache.windows.net". This is the error I get:

E/flutter ( 4861): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(209)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 4861): RedisError(NOAUTH Authentication required.)

[old package](https://github.com/dartist/redis_client) This is the package starred on [Redis Website](https://redis.io/clients#dart). But it's incompatible on versions >2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution. Use your key in the following way:

For [redis 1.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/redis):

```
...
 RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
    conn
        .connect('SampleName.redis.cache.windows.net', 6379)
        .then((Command command) {
      print("yo2");
      command.send_object([
        "AUTH",
        "<YourKey>"
      ]).then((var response) {
        print(response);
      });

      command.send_object(["SET", "key1", "value1"]);
    });
...
```

And for [dartis 0.5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/dartis):

```
...
final client = await redis.Client.connect(
        'redis://SampleName.redis.cache.windows.net:6379');

    // Runs some commands.
    final commands = client.asCommands<String, String>();
    await commands.auth("<YourKey>");
    // SET key value
    await commands.set('yo', 'yovalue');
...
```